# react redux with CDN links without ES6 or Webpack

Tags: reactjs, redux, cdn

I am new to react redux and I can't find any simple example of react redux with CDN links (almost all of them are with npm). So is there any example of react redux with CDN links?

Comment: The beginning for REACT is quite a little difficult for beginner, Usually you need to setup things, not just place some script and It works. I recommend trying Vue instead. Here's an example doing so: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/133/How-to-Install-Vue-2---Through-CDN,-NPM-and-the-Vue-CLI

Comment: you could try this https://codesandbox.io/ initially

Answer (score 0):

You can check and see examples [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html), [redux](https://gist.github.com/wvengen/bd7fb12c2afd9c251eb166f1bd042f51) for react dev mode without any build tool. You can load it directly in a html file.